# Shotwell develop raw files on import

Tags: shotwell

In the preferences one can set the default raw developer, leading to each raw beeing developed the first time opened.

However I am able to force the development process if I manually switch the raw developer for selected photos, thus getting developed versions of each selected image.

Is it possible to develop images using the default raw developer on import?
Or do I need to keep using my dirty(and expensive) trick?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

As the person who wrote this bit of code, I guess I should jump in and explain.

Originally Shotwell developed RAW photos at import time.  This annoyed a lot of photographers who shoot RAW, because it mean imports could take hours to complete!

So we made a couple of changes:

1. RAW photos would be developed the first time they're opened.
2. A preference option lets you select between Shotwell developed photos and Camera developed photos, where the camera developer represents embedded JPEGs or the JPEG from a RAW+JPEG pair.

I hope that explains why Shotwell works this way.

Now as to your issue, it seems you've found an interesting workaround.  I'm afraid I can't offer a better solution or workaround, but I would point out that you can select multiple RAW photos and change the developer on all of them at once.